# Converting datetime formatted index to date only python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, indexing, formatting

I have a dataframe with an index formatted in datetime as such:

```
2019-01-01 00:00:00+00:00
2019-01-02 00:00:00+00:00
2019-01-03 00:00:00+00:00
```

I would like to only keep the year - month - day component without having to change the index back to a column and then back to index

Desired result:

```
2019-01-01
2019-01-02
2019-01-03
```

I have been struggling for quite some time. Hope this hasn't been asked before. Thanks for your input! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [pandas.DatetimeIndex.date](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.date.html)

```py
df.index = df.index.date
```

If your index is string not datetime type, convert it to datetime with

```py
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
df['yourcol'] = df['col'].dt.date
```

Also if in the index

```
df.index = df.index.date
```